# How does Time Machine handle backing up an external drive that may be disconnected?

Tags: backup, time-machine, external-disk

I currently backup my MacBook Air to a NAS using Time Machine and all is well. I often, but not always, have an external SSD connected to my MBA that I would also like to be backed up. If I simply dis-exclude the external drive and allow TM to do its thing, will everything work out ok if it sometimes runs a backup without the external SSD connected? When the drive is reconnected, will TM think the files are new and add them back to the latest snapshot? I feel like this might eat up a lot of space, but I'm not sure how smart it is.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you exclude the external drive from the backup list at times at all? If connected, it will be backed up and, if not, it will wait to back it up until it is reconnected.

Comment: Remove the drive from the exclusion list, permanently. It will back up the drive if it's connected, and won't back it up if it's not connected. It will only backup the delta each time.

Comment: Ok, great. I've never backed up the external drive. I was waiting to do so until I knew it would work properly. Thanks